# VBA Autofill for every row

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

First of all, I dont have any experience with VBA. What i have here is based on what i've read from various tutorial.
I have data in Excel sheet that i wanted to insert into the bookmarks in MS Word as auto-fill. Each row of data will be saved as one MS Word doc file. The problem i'm having is i dont know how to continuously auto-fill on the next row until the row in column A is blank

```
Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim myDoc As Word.Document
Dim mywdRange As Word.Range
Dim Tagno As Range
Dim Csheetno As Range

Set wdApp = New Word.Application
With wdApp
.Visible = True
.WindowState = wdWindowStateMaximize
End With

'Autofill start
'-----Set Range-----
Set myDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add(Template:="C:\Template\" & Range("B2") & ".docx")
Set Tagno = Sheets("Autofill").Range("A2")
Set Csheetno = Sheets("Autofill").Range("B2")

'-----Paste to msWord bookmarks-----
With myDoc.Bookmarks
.Item("tagno").Range.InsertAfter Tagno
.Item("csheetno").Range.InsertAfter Csheetno
End With

myDoc.SaveAs "C:" & "\" & Range("A2") & "_" & Range("B2") & ".docx"
myDoc.Close False
wdApp.Quit

Set doc = Nothing
Set wd = Nothing
```

Comment: Why not automate a mailmerge? For the mailmerge basics, see: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Mail-merge-using-an-Excel-spreadsheet-858C7D7F-5CC0-4BA1-9A7B-0A948FA3D7D3. For mailmerge automation from Excel, see *Run a Mailmerge from Excel, Sending the Output to Individual Files* at: http://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html

Comment: i have thought of mail merge but the that doesnt suit my situation because im using a lot of different templates and i simply dont understand mail merge even from your link

Comment: The use of 'a lot of different templates' doesn't negate the use of mailmerge; it just shows you may need to spend some time learning how to combine them into a single mailmerge main document. Alternatively, a few changes to the macro I provided a link for will allow you to choose which mailmerge main document to use in a given case.

Comment: im not a programmer and limited knowledge of coding. 'a few changes' might not sound so easy for me. anyway thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Try something based on:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document, r As Long
'Hide Word
wdApp.Visible = False
'Create, populate & save Word documents, 1 per row.
With Sheets("Autofill")
  For r = 2 To .UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    If .Range("A" & r).Text = "" Then GoTo ErrExit
    'Create document
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add(Template:="C:\Template\" & .Range("B" & r).Text & ".docx")
    '-----Update Word bookmarks-----
    wdDoc.Bookmarks("tagno").Range.InsertAfter .Range("A" & r).Text
    wdDoc.Bookmarks("csheetno").Range.InsertAfter .Range("B" & r).Text
    'Save & close document
    wdDoc.SaveAs "C:" & "\" & .Range("A" & r).Text & "_" & .Range("B" & r).Text & ".docx", _
      FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False
    wdDoc.Close False
  Next
End With
ErrExit:
wdApp.Quit
Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Note:** You should be using Word templates as templates, not Word documents.